# Migrating an app from one windows app store account to new store account

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps

I have a requirement to transfer an app from a windows store account to a new store account. Also I would need all the information like description, ratings, comments etc to be migrated to the new account along with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the Windows store support for that.